# Massalin's Synthesis Quajects equivalent to ASM generating macros used in Game Oriented Assembly LISP?

Tags: operating-systems

[Alexia Massalin's Dissertation on Synthesis](http://valerieaurora.org/synthesis/SynthesisOS/abs.html) was a Phd thesis on Operating Systems that contained a concept called 'Quajects' (see [Chapter 4](http://valerieaurora.org/synthesis/SynthesisOS/ch4.html)).

This is some [additional commentary on the Phd Thesis](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4030665).

Best I can work out - a Quaject is construct that generates Assembler customised for the function being used at the time. (Perhaps like a [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)).

The project that I've seen that came closest to this was [Game Oriented Assembly LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp) (GOAL), a framework used in Crash Bandicoot that used ASM-generating LISP macros to speed up the development iteration process and generate the production code.

Can we say that the Macros generating ASM in GOAL were quajects? (yes or no question - please explain why if yes, and reasons if no.)

Comment: Do you seriously mean to ask a yes/no question?

Comment: :) if yes - tell me why. If no - tell me your reasons.

Comment: Why don't you change the question to reflect that? Or perhaps change it to "how".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, a Quaject is a kind of [*software component*](http://www2.lirmm.fr/~tibermacin/ens/fmin332/articles/mdlComps.pdf) in the sense that it has a **provided** interface (the *callentry* functions), which contains the functions it offers, and a **required** interface (the *callout* functions), which contains the functions it needs  to operate. The *callback* part of the interface is for **call back** functions, which are functions that are available to call the caller of a function. (In Java you cannot call the caller unless an explicit reference is passed.)

I don't think it is correct to say that "a Quaject is construct that generates Assembler customised for the function being used at the time." For example, in Section 4.1.4 of the thesis it states that

> Higher-level kernel services are built by composing several basic
>   quajects.

So the quajects are the ingredients that are used to build the custom services. They do not build them.

[GOAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp) seems to be a variant of Scheme that allows inline assembly language, which I can image allows quite some flexibility in the programming. The language is compiled to assembly. The assembly language it includes is not in the shape of any sort of component, as far as I can tell.

Based on this, I would say that the answer to your question is **no**.

Comment: Thanks Dave - really appreciate your thoughts. I've added some additional commentary on the Thesis that I should have included originally - which may clarify where my question was coming from. I've also taken your advice and clarified the question.

Comment: The problem with the additional commentary link is that the reference to quajects is embedded in some larger less relevant text. I don't know whether it makes sense to quote the relevant text in your question.

Comment: Oh well - thanks for reading it anyway.

Comment: Maybe just link to the relevant chunk -- each part can be linked to (click the link button).